# two Horizontol scroll bars

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, html, codepen

Am having two scroll bars in my website as i embed calendar widget from code pen
https://codepen.io/jpag82/pen/Nazayx/

**Two scroll bars**

[image]

one scroll bar moves the body and the other moves the whole page as am using asp.net mvc5 so i called my header footer and side bar from shared layout. using

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

just hides the scroll bar of main page.

here you can see the image of single  scroll bars which just moves the inner body

**Single scroll**

[image]

how to remove the scroll bar which moves the inner body ?

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: how to remove the scroll bar which moves the inner body ,, i want only one initial scroll bar wich moves the whole page

Comment: Do you have a defined height for the container that contains the scroll-element? Might help with setting the height of that element to auto

Comment: @KasperRynning-Tønnesen before embedding the calendar widget it is working fine, but after that its showing me like this , and now its hard for me to get it

Comment: Add your code -_-

Comment: @thebrownkid i have added the link of codepen from where i pick up the widget

Comment: @Aqib I've seen it and is partial code as the issue you are facing is on the page and not on the widget. It will be easy for everyone to find the best possible fix for you if we have the code of the page where you are placing the widget. Otherwise, everyone will be guessing the possible fixes as you can see on your post.

Comment: thanks for your time @thebrownkid the problem is in the height of the calendar widget and the overflow is in auto that is why this problem occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the inner container for the calendar widgets has a fixed height, and is set to scroll if overflow. The way to solve your problem will be to change the fixed height of the inner container to "height: auto".

Take for example the code below, widget-container has a fixed height in css, so it creates its own scrollbar on overflow, but when you click on the button, the height is toggled to 'auto', so the inner scrollbar disappears, and all the scrolling is now on body: notice how body scrollbar shrinks, when you click the button.

That should fix your issue.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var widgetContainer = document.getElementById("widget-container");
var hasFixedHeight = true;
btn.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    if (hasFixedHeight) {
       widgetContainer.classList.add("height-auto");
       hasFixedHeight = false;
    } else {
      widgetContainer.classList.remove("height-auto");
      hasFixedHeight = true;
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.fixed-container {
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.height-auto {
  height: auto;
}

.content {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  Here is body, parent container of everything.
  <div id="widget-container" class="fixed-container">
    Here is the parent container to the calendar widgets
    <button id="btn" type="button">toggle scrollbar</button>
    <div class="content">
      Here is where the content, that is, your calendar widgets will be.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to be scrolling on.
Look for the inner element that displays the scroll, and change the CSS

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: i did this but it hides the initial scroll bar the inner scroll bar remains the same

Comment: where to find inner element?

Answer (score 0):

All your content in the inner scroll is somewhat set to scroll i guess

```
    overflow-y: hidden;
```

Should work fine just use it on the parent div containing the whole content in which the inner scrollbar is appearing